# Javascript else if not working for all statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the javascript to make the div slide up and down faster or slower when a user selects a value from a select menu. The javascript doesn't work at all. How am I supposed to make the div slide faster/slower with the `if/ else if`
function?

HTML:

```
<p class="explanation">
This snippet will show you how to make the <i>Bouncing Div</i> animation, using <a href="http://jquery.com" target="_blank">Jquery</a> and <a href="http://jqueryui.com" target="_blank">Jquery UI</a><br>Click <a href="http://api.jquery.com" target="_blank">here</a> to familiarize yourself with Jquery. 
</p>

<p class="explanation">
Click <button>here</button> to start the animation on the below div.
</p>
Select your speed here:
<select id="select-speed">
<option value="">Select speed</option>
<option value=".5x">.5x</option>
<option value="1x">1x</option>
<option value="2x">2x</option>
</select>
then click the button above.
<div class="experiment-div">

</div>
```

JS:

```
var ex = $('.experiment-div');
$('.experiment-div').show();

var starter = $('button');
var stopper = $('input[type=button]');
var i = 0;
var select = $('#select-speed').val();
starter.click(function () {
    while (i < 1000) {
        ex.slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);
        i++;
    }
    if (select == '1x') {
        while (i < 1000) {
            ex.slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);
            i++;
        }
    } else if (select == '.5x') {
        while (i < 1000) {
            ex.slideUp(4000).slideDown(4000);
            i++;
        }
    } else if (select == '2x') {
        while (i < 1000) {
            ex.slideUp(1000).slideDown(1000);
            i++;
        }
    }
    ex.append('<p>Cool, huh?</p><p>More coming soon!</p>');
});
```

Am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the console? Are you linking jQuery on the page?

Comment: Why do you have those `while` statements? You really want the animation to run 1000 times?

Comment: What do you think the while loops are doing? Yikes

Comment: @hopkins-matt, yes, I do want it to run 1000 times and the while loops are making the animation repeat itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are most likely not linking jQuery.

You'll need to add this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Uncomment the first line of the demo to see it work.

**Demo**: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/ag8jvkLh/1/)

---

### EDIT

I took another look. I was thrown off by the comment, "The javascript doesn't work at all." It does work, but not correctly. The problem is the while loop is placing 1000 animations in the queue. Even though the `if/else if` statements are working, the new animations are even further down the queue. I rewrote the script to use `.stop()` to clear the queue, and I think this is what you are looking for.

JS:

```
var ex = $('.experiment-div');
$('.experiment-div').show();

var starter = $('button');
var stopper = $('input[type=button]');

function animateDiv(speed) {
    var i = 0;
    while(i < 1000) {
        i++;
        ex.slideUp(speed).slideDown(speed);
    }
}
    
starter.click(function() {
    ex.stop(true,true);
    var select = $('#select-speed').val();
    ex.append('<p>Cool, huh?</p><p>More coming soon!</p>');
    if (select == '1x') {
        animateDiv(2000);
        console.log('fired 1x');
    } else if (select == '.5x') {
        animateDiv(4000);
        console.log('fired .5x');
    } else if (select == '2x') {
        animateDiv(1000);
        console.log('fired 2x');
    } else {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

**New Demo**: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/ag8jvkLh/4/)

Comment: I am linking jquery. I have other things on that page that require jquery, and those work. It's not the jquery.

Comment: Works fine in the fiddle once jQuery is linked. Do you have a URL for the page having the issue?

Comment: Ok, take a look at my edited answer. I think it should work for you.